# How to solve this problem on partial derivatives?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Given, $$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{2}\tan u.\tag{1}$$

Find $$x^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+y^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}+2xy\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial yx}.$$

**My method**
Operate with $$x\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$ on both sides of the given equation.

Then L.H.S =  $$x^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+y^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}+2xy\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial yx}.$$

R.H.S = $$x\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{1}{2}\tan u)=\frac{x}{2}\sec^2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{y}{2}\sec^2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\= \frac{1}{2\cos^2u} (x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y})\\=\frac{1}{2\cos^2u}\frac{1}{2}\tan u \\= \frac{\tan u}{4\cos^2u}.$$

Is there something wrong with my method? The answer seems to be different in my textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LHS seems wrong. There are some missing terms. $$x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)=x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+x^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$$
Similarly for $y$.